# angular typescript write test for random username method

Tags: angular, testing, random

i started learnin Angular and Typescript and i have to test this method but i dont know how to test Random return . if you can help me would really appreciate

```
botRandName(): string {
        const x: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        if (x === 1) return (this.botName = 'player1');
        else if (x === 2) return (this.botName = 'player2');
        else return (this.botName = 'player3');
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your function - to have the ability to pass specific condition:

```
function botRandName(x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)) {
  if (x === 1) return (this.botName = "player1");
  else if (x === 2) return (this.botName = "player2");
  else return (this.botName = "player3");
}
```

```
describe("Testing botRandName", () => {
  it("should test", () => {
    expect(botRandName(1)).toBe("player1");
    expect(botRandName(2)).toBe("player2");
    expect(botRandName(3)).toBe("player3");
  });
});
```

Comment: it it helped you please mark my answer as correct

Comment: Thank you so much